# Access a file other than jar in local maven repository

Tags: maven, path, installation, native, executable

Is it possible to read as a consumer some resource files (not jars) from a maven repository?

I am able to install them with commands like:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=mycommand -DgroupId=mygroupid -DartifactId=myartifactid -Dpackaging=bin -Dversion=1`

The file `mycommand` is a regular native executable which I'd like to install and possibly deploy on my local repository.

The reason I am doing this is that I'd like, in another maven project, to retrieve this file and access it (and possibly use it through an `exec:exec` goal).

I know that maven is basically for jar distribution and management, but there are cases that small native work might be required in a big java project, and it would be better to have it all together, packed as required instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deploying the file to repository**

It's possible to put binary files in your local/company Maven repository.

More details here:
[Upload linux binary file to maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612768/upload-linux-binary-file-to-maven-repository)

**Using it in another build**

That can be achieved via [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

Here's an example from one project how to copy a WAR file built elsewhere.
The idea is to add it as a dependency and then have a step to copy it to a folder of your choosing:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-artifact-to-copy</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy.some.artifact</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: My question is more how to retrieve this file back, not how to install it. I am able to install it by using the command I describe.